# Android SQLite Update Table no return

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

- When First Insert data **it Works**
- But When I update Query it **doesn't work**

Here is my code what I'm trying to do.

```
fun updateData(mData: Data) {
            if (!databaseOpen) {
                database = INSTANCE.writableDatabase
                databaseOpen = true
            }
  val values = ContentValues()

values.put(DatabaseConstan.USER_ID, mData.userId)
values.put(DatabaseConstan.ABOUT, mData.userInfo.about)


return database.update(DatabaseConstan.DATABASE_TABEL, values, "${DatabaseConstan.USER_ID}=${mData.userId}", null);
```

But this method works

```
 return  database.execSQL("UPDATE data SET userId=${mData.userId} WHERE id='1'");
```

Here is Create Table Command

```
 val QUERY_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE  $DATABASE_TABEL ($ROW_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $USER_ID INTEGER , $ABOUT TEXT)"
```

I'm confused and trying but con't understand

Answer (score 0):

The `mData` object contains the new values of 3 columns that you want to replace the old values. 
So `mData.userId` contains the new `userId` that does not exist in the table.
This makes the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement, which is the 3d argument of the method `update()`: `"${DatabaseConstan.USER_ID}=${mData.userId}"` to return nothing.

So instead of `${mData.userId}` you must use the original value of the column which you must save in a variable like `currentUserId` and change to:

```
"${DatabaseConstan.USER_ID}=$currentUserId"
```

Or maybe you want to set the `WHERE` clause so you search by `id` and not by `userId` and assuming that the `mData` object contains the `id` also:

```
"${DatabaseConstan.ID}=${mData.Id}"
```

Change the names of the variables to your actual names.